# Dataframe with date index returns empty when filtered by date

Tags: dataframe

I have a function which suddenly stops to work properly. I don't make any change relative to it (even if obviously, something has changed :)) Up to now, the function was returning a smaller DataFrame but since today, it returns an empty DataFrame. Here is the code and the ouptputs of the couple of print I have added to try to understand the issue:

```
def candlestick(df: pd.DataFrame, days=364):

    end_date = df.index.max()
    start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=days)
    print(f'start: {start_date}')
    print(f'end: {end_date}')
    print(df)
    graph_df = df[start_date:end_date]
    print(graph_df)
```

Outputs:

```
start: 2023-02-10
end: 2024-02-09
                 id  share_id    Open    High     Low   Close
Date
2024-02-09  1130794       246  134.51  135.74  132.92  135.49
2024-02-08  1130793       246  132.03  135.98  131.00  134.12
2024-02-07  1130792       246  126.63  128.21  126.36  128.08
2024-02-06  1130791       246  126.72  127.15  125.72  126.33
2024-02-05  1130790       246  127.99  127.99  126.52  126.75
...             ...       ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2005-11-22  1126211       246    7.09    7.09    6.86    6.99
2005-11-21  1126210       246    7.05    7.19    6.96    7.18
2005-11-18  1126209       246    7.24    7.39    6.91    7.00
2005-11-17  1126208       246    8.06    8.35    6.80    7.05
2005-11-16  1126207       246    7.80    8.84    7.71    7.85

[4588 rows x 6 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, share_id, Open, High, Low, Close]
Index: []
```

There is probably something obvious somewhere but I can't see it. Thanks for any tips which could lead me to solution

Comment: Your data is printing all the way back to 2005, but it looks like you aren’t trying to go that far back in your constraints (start and end dates). Is that an error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No it is not an error. This code set up the data to display a candlestick graph over the last year but I have more data in DB for statistical purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data frame becomes empty because it is in descending order. You should use `df[end_date:start_date]`, or swap the definitions of `start_date` and `end_date`, or reverse the order of the data frame if that was the intention.

You can easily reproduce and verify this:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(1.0, index=pd.date_range(start='2005-11-16', end='2024-02-09', freq='1d'), columns=['A'])
df = df.iloc[::-1, :]  # reversing the default ascending order

end_date = df.index.max()
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=364)
start_date, end_date
# => (Timestamp('2023-02-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-02-09 00:00:00'))

df[start_date:end_date]
# => empty data frame

df[end_date:start_date]
# => non-empty data frame indexed by dates in descending order
```

Comment: THanks. I knew it was something too obvious. Now I have to find why it is not in ascending order as the dataframe is supposed to be fit for the function earlier.